# First item from Listview selector enabled

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-selector

when I add items to a listview using a custom adapter, the first element selector is always activated.
there is some way to disable this operation.

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewMaterials"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="@color/buttonblue"/>
```

java:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, GetData(modelResult));
            ListViewMaterials.setAdapter(adapter);
```